# Highchart.js is not working properly in pure IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm using highchart.js v4.2.2 in jsp. In pure IE8 it is not working properly, tooltip does not hide overlapping with existing data. If use a higher IE version in the IE8 compatibility mode, it works, but not in pure IE8.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This might be related to a known issue with VML rendering issues in older IE versions (e.g., IE8). See [this bug report](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/1742) and [this forum post](https://forum.highcharts.com/highstock-usage/artifacts-left-from-tooltips-in-ie7-and-ie8-t12824/#p56839) for more details.

A proposed workaround is to use full HTML and CSS for the tooltip. For example:

JS:

```
tooltip: {
    useHTML: true,
    borderWidth: 0,
    backgroundColor: null,
    shadow: false,
    style: {
    padding: 0
}
```

CSS:

```
.highcharts-tooltip {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.highcharts-tooltip span {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px #666;
}

.highcharts-tooltip span span {
    background-color: none;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;    
}
```